# Activity was restored twice when the orientation changes

Tags: android, oncreate, android-orientation

I am having some problems with an activity of my Android aplication.

I have discovered that my app enters twice in 'onCreateView()' method of this activity when orientation changes, and it is causing me problems. When I click the corresponding button and this activity starts is all ok, but whithin this activity when the orientation changes I have some problems because enters twice, i.e. activity restarts twice ...

... Does anyone know the behaviour of an activity when orientation changes? Why does this happen?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Do you have anything in `onStart()`?

Comment: No, i do not have that method.

Answer (score 2):

Since `onCreateView()` is not part of the Activity lifecycle, but rather is part of the Fragment, I would assume you have a fragment somewhere in your activity. 
Also I would assume you add this fragment manually using `FragmentManager` and `FragmentTransaction`. Since Android keeps all the added fragments between orientation changes, it is quite possible that you don't check if your Fragment is already present in this activity, so you add it again which causes additional `onCreateView` to be called.

If this is the case - you need to check if your `savedInstance` is null within `onCreate`. If it is - you add fragment. Otherwise activity is getting restored, so fragment is already there.

A lot of assumptions for the answer, I know. But I'm still mastering my telepathy skills :)

Comment: Yes @Pavel, it is a Fragment loaded in an activity, I add it using FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction and I have `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()` methods ... I should have seen it. Should I delete   'onCreate()' method? How I check if there is another fragment before? Ty

Comment: But I use `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.xxx, fragment).commit();` not `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.xxx, fragment).commit();` ... then I do not add another fragment, I replace the fragment

Comment: you should call fragment replace from Activity's onCreate. Not from Fragment's. Please make sure this is the case

Answer (score 0):

When orientation changes onDestroy() is called, followed by onCreate().
For more : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in **AndroidMainfest.xml** in your activity:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

This means not to recreate the activity when orientation changes.